# How to scale texture with camera distance while keeping the texture tied to the axis of the object

Tags: texturing

Say I had a wave texture on two cubes- one in the foreground and one in the background relative to the camera. From the camera's perspective I'd like the size of the waves to be the same for both cubes no matter where i view from (as you would see with window texture coordinates) but if I view the cubes on an angle with the camera, the wave texture stays relative to the object's axis and not the camera's (as you would see with object texture coordinates).

I appreciate any help I could get with this- Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the object to swim through the texture, I guess the scaling of the texture has to be an approximation?

An exact scaling by the distance of the *shading point* to the camera would cause the texture to distort.. so is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Here, the texture is in Object space, but scaled by `1 / [distance from object to camera]`

[image]

These cubes are identical. There's an optical illusion that the screen-size of the texture is getting bigger as they recede... [but that's all it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzo_illusion).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you so much for this.

If I could ask one step further- Is it at all possible to have the textures on the sides of the cubes to face the camera as well but keep the x+y rotation of the object?

Comment: @Stray_Dog_  I'm not understanding this one, sorry.. .. then the texture wouldn't 'stay relative to the object's axis' ?  Could you think of a way of illustrating what you mean?

Comment: @Stray_Dog_  Ahh.. maybe you want to project the texture from the camera, but _then_ have it stick to the objects?

Comment: [Here's](https://imgur.com/GlgY0N7) my issue. [Windowed coordinates](https://imgur.com/i5TvZ9J) have only a part of the answer. I'm new to posting images here so sorry if these don't work.

Comment: Just thinking more about this and the question doesn't really make much sense with perspective and might be just a weird impossible thing that only made sense in my mind for a second hah.

Comment: @Stray_Dog_ will check tomorrow, it's late, GMT :)

Comment: It looks as though you might want an [isometric projection](https://www.blender3darchitect.com/architectural-visualization/create-true-isometric-camera-architecture/) ?.

Comment: Right- that makes total sense. I've not yet mastered the isometric style so it looks like I should give it some work. Thanks for your help with all of this- I really appreciate it!